# How do I get this Case statement to work in Oracle vs SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

The Failure field populates both 'Fail' and 'Non-Fail' in SQL Server. Oracle only populates 'Fail'

```
Select
    A.order_no, FS.order_no
    ,case when FS.order_no is Null then 'Non-Fail' else 'Fail' end as Failure
From 
    dbo.orders A
    left join dbo.failures FS
    on A.order_no = FS.order_no
```

Comment: and are you sure that there are actual `NULL`s there?

Comment: You could try using NVL     something like....   

    WHEN NVL(FS.order_no,'XXX') = 'XXX' THEN

Comment: I am almost 100% certain that the statement produces the same result in both DBMS given the **same** input data.

Comment: what you are using is a "case **expression**"; a "case statement" is something else, refer https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/case-expressions-and-statements-9i

Answer (score 1):

The statement will work the same in Oracle without any modifications.

The difference in the results is most likely due to differences in the data you are using to test it.

Comment: Using **IS NULL** is a good and generic method and the existing case expression is valid on both Oracle and SQL Server. It does not need amendment. There may unexpected conditions in the data that cause you to think the query isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the NVL2 function, which is used for conditional statements for comparing null values.
NVL2(exp1,exp2,exp3) :return exp2 if exp1 is not null, else exp3.
Try this :

`Select
    A.order_no, FS.order_no,
    NVL2(FS.order_no,'Fail','non-Fail') as Failure
From 
    dbo.orders A
    left join dbo.failures FS
    on A.order_no = FS.order_no`